# Should original order be referenced on every subsequent invoice record in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, e-commerce, recurring-billing

Consider the following database design (irrelevant columns and tables removed):

[image: Database Design Illustration]

Each time a recurring payment is due for a subscription, I intend to add an invoice record and subsequent payment record.

However, given orders can contain both **one-off** purchases, and **subscription** purchases, is it normal practice to reference the original `order_id` when generating new monthly invoices?

My hesitation, if not clear, is that the original `order` record *may* include items that are not subscriptions, and as such, are not relevant to the recurring invoices.

Comment: *given orders can contain both one-off purchases, and subscription purchases, is it normal practice to reference the original order_id when generating new monthly invoices?* I'd prefer that each purchase is subscriptional one. And one-off/reusable is subscription attribute.

Comment: 'original order record may include items that are not subscriptions' - I am not clear what you mean by this , are you saying some of the order_items can include items which can be paid by subscription and items which cannot for the same order(s)? BTW order is not a good name in my view, order_header would be better..

Comment: @P.Salmon - The best example I can give is imagine a basket on a store that contains; ethernet cable, network switch, and then a router with an accompnying broadband subscription. The ethernet cable and switch are physical items, as is the router, but the router is paired with a subscription as well. Does that make sense?

Comment: In your comment example, the cable, switch, and router lease would be charged in the first invoice and subsequent invoices would just have the router lease.  Your payment rows need to refer to the order line rows, but they should be in a separate table.  What are you going to do if the customer makes a partial payment?  What are you going to do if the customer makes no payment?

Comment: FWIW, I think it's a mistake for referential keys to be anything other than integers. I know that others disagree, but to my mind, ids should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database

Comment: Show us a `SELECT` that would stumble over the existence or absence of `order_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a matter of opinion.

The original order contains the order for the subscription.  That it contains other information is rather irrelevant.  *You care about the order where the subscription first appears.*

Keeping the original order id seems reasonable.  In fact, when an invoice is created it is probably a best practice to have information about the original order for the items on the invoice.  Otherwise, it becomes much more cumbersome to check the lineage of the items -- something that might be quite important for auditing purposes and other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

- Any order item can be 0 cost.
- A subscription item is 0 cost order. Item should generate an entry in a table which relates customer and service bought (at 0 cost) from which an invoice can be generated in whatever periodicity and amount the contract states.
- The only difference between an invoice and payments is direction. Have one table with sufficient information to identify the invoice for (sum of payable order items and order id) or subscription items (customer id and service id).
- The customer will not identify the payment unless you manage payment collection by direct debit, so you have to code for allocation of funds received (refunded, refused etc.).
- Do you really need an invoice (isn't that the same as an order if every order is billable?).

Answer (score 1):

- Redundant info is (usually) a no-no in database design.
- If you need an 'extra' `JOIN` to get the desired info, so be it.  This is rarely a reason to clutter the schema with an extra column.